# Comparing two JsonArray nodes in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a method that gets two Json nodes that should be Json array nodes of different sizes.
I need to check if ArrayA contains all the elements of ArrayB. How do I do that?

```
private boolean isContains (JsonNode ArrayA, JsonNode ArrayB) {

    if (ArrayA.isArray() && ArrayB.isArray()) {
        // Here goes the missing code.
    }
}
```

Comment: By documentation `equals` should work in depth, see http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: They are not equal. In Java, we have a method list.contains(anotherList). Is there something similar in Jackson?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. The other answers are appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no inbuilt method I can see, but `JsonNode` implements `Iteratable` so you can loop through both and do a compare. Something along the lines of:

```
boolean matches = true;

for (JsonNode nodeB : arrayB)
{
   boolean matchesInternal = false;

   for (JsonNode nodeA : arrayA)
   {
      if (nodeA.equals(nodeB))
      {
          matchesInternal = true;
          break;
      }
   }

   if (!matchesInternal) {
      matches = false;
      break;
   }
}

return matches;
```

Comment: could it be I have no matches() method?

Comment: I used nodeA.**asText()**.equals(nodeB.**asText()**) to compare the nodes as strings and it worked just fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Alex if you check the `asText()` documentation, you will see it will return empty strings for compound elements, so that is a not too good solution, different things will be considered equals.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I mistyped that. `equals` would be correct. I don't know that you have to call `asText()`.

Answer (score 2):

The [JSON Patch](https://github.com/fge/json-patch) reverse part might do what you are looking for.

See: https://github.com/fge/json-patch#json-diff-factorization

Edit:
It is as easy as:

```
JsonNode diff = JsonDiff.asJson(first, second);
```

And than you can check whether `diff` contains removes or adds or both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zjsonpatch](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch) library, which presents the diff information in accordance with RFC 6902 (JSON Patch). Its very easy to use. Please visit its description page for its usage.
This library is better than fge-json-patch (which was mentioned in above answer) because it can detect correctly items being inserted/removed from arrays.

Answer (score 0):

For those who faced the same problem but prefer more flat code. You can use the Apache Commons's IterableUtils.toList() to convert the ArrayNode#elements() to List and then perform List#containsAll() operation to check whether they contain the same elements. It will look like this:

```
sourceArray.size() == targetArray.size() && IteratorUtils.toList(sourceArray.elements()).containsAll(IteratorUtils.toList(targetArray.elements()))
```